# how to install easydropdown with Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, easydropdown

What is the correct way to install `easydropdown` into Rails 6?

I ran `yarn add easydropdown` to add it to my app.  Seems ok; I verified that my browser sees it in the js sources.

After this, not totally sure what to do.  In app/javascripts/packs/application.js, I've tried adding these lines.  None cause errors.

- `require('easydropdown')`
- `import easydropdown from 'easydropdown'`
- `import Easydropdown from 'easydropdown'` - does case matter?

But in my page and js console, I keep seeing `easydropdown is not defined`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ben-trewern for helping me get here.

For Rails 6, here's what works for me:

1. `yarn add easydropdown` to install it into your Rails App
2. Append loader code to `app/javascripts/packs/application.js`.

   I've found 2 ways that work.  I honestly don't know which is better or why.

   **Option 1:** using `import`

   ```
   import easydropdown from 'easydropdown';
   window.easydropdown = easydropdown;
   ```

   **Option 2:** using `require`

   ```
   const easydropdown = require('easydropdown')
   window.easydropdown = easydropdown.default
   ```
3. Now you can use `easydropdown` functions in your views (including `<script>` tags).

**Bonus help: Are you using Stimulus JS?**

If your dropdown is connected to a Stimulus controller, here's some tips:

I found that I still had to assign `window.easydropdown` (above) in order to call EDD in my controller code.

Seems the most straightforward thing to do is to call `easydropdown.select('#my-select')` in my Stimulus controller's `initialize()` method, e.g.

```
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [...]
  initialize() {
    easydropdown.select('#region-switcher`);
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When using webpack the require statements are not global so you need to require the library in the file in which you are using it.

In your application.js pack file add the following:

```
import easydropdown from 'easydropdown';

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  easydropdown('.easydropdown')
});
```

as long as your selects have class of "easydropdown" this should make them all work.

Your styles need to be added either in your assets or imported in this pack file as well.

Comment: I put it in a script tag in my view and I got: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Comment: This does not work in <script> tags embedded in pages.  You have to include this code either in your application.js pack file or a file required in that file.  I've also changed my answer as this needs to run when the page loads. Assuming you are using Turbolinks.

Comment: I have appended `const easydropdown = require('easydropdown')` to my `app/javascripts/packs/application.js` file, and there's no error, but I still get `easydropdown is not defined` in my view.  Should I be able to reference that `easydropdown` var in a `<script>` tag or the js console?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use import instead of require.  This works properly, I've just tested it.

Comment: Changed my application.js file, but still getting `easydropdown is not defined` when I try to invoke it in js console.  (Are you in Rails 5 or 6?  Not sure if that matters, but it might.)

Comment: As I said in the answer, when using require or in this case import, nothing in webpack is global.  It will not be available in the console or in <script> tags in your views.

Comment: If you need to enable this in <script> tags, add window.easydropdown = easydropdown to you application.js file.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, that got me there.